# Objective-C Plugin Architecture Security (Mac, not iPhone)

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, architecture, plugins

I'm possibly writing a plugin system for a Cocoa application (Mac, not iPhone).

A common approach is the make each plugin a bundle, then inject the bundle into the main application. I'm concerned with the security implications of doing this, as the bundle will have complete access to the Objective-C runtime. I am especially concerned with a plugin having access to the code that handles registration and serial keys.

Another plugin system we are considering is based on distributed notifications. Basically, each plugin will be a separate process, and they will communicate via distributed notifications only.

Is there a way to load bundles securely (e.g. sandboxing)? If not, do you see any problems with using distributed notifications? Are there any other plugin architectures that would be better?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, OS X has [sandboxing support](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man7/sandbox.7.html#//apple_ref/doc/man/7/sandbox) on a per-process level.  The only open-source third-party client I'm aware of is [Chrome](http://src.chromium.org/cgi-bin/gitweb.cgi?p=chromium.git;a=blob;f=chrome/common/sandbox_mac.mm).  You could also investigate a wrapper such as [Native Client](http://code.google.com/p/nativeclient/).

That said, there's really no point in trying to sandbox plugins for security reasons, unless you're loading untrusted plugins or content over the network (i.e. a web browser).  If someone wants to crack your application locally, they can just use a debugger, DTrace, etc.

What IPC mechanism you use between your app and plugin processes really depends on the type of communication you're doing. Intermachine Distributed Objects (I assume that's what you meant to write) is certainly not a bad choice for most purposes, but you wouldn't want to send video over it.  You might check out [CoreIPC](http://trac.webkit.org/browser/trunk/WebKit2/Platform/CoreIPC), which the under-development [WebKit2](http://trac.webkit.org/wiki/WebKit2) uses; it works over Mach ports.

Comment: Thanks for the sandboxing link. I was actually talking about `NSDistributedNotificationCenter`, but I'll have a better look at distributed objects. My worry with bundles is that plugin developers will use `objc_getClassList` and start swizzling/calling methods that they shouldn't be touching, whether that's for cracking purposes or not. It sounds like a separate process is definitely the way to go.