# how to add one or more plugins to an existing app

Tags: ios, iphone, ipad, plugins, app-store

My company want to make an application which like a bookshelf can load more books when the application finished, they want the application to be able to load more plugins without destroying the already installed code: when the app has been purchased and downloaded from the app store, the user can buy plugins in the app store and install them into the app.

Can anyone tell me how this could be achieved? Thank you very much.

Answer (score 3):

- [Implementing A Plugin System in C or C++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/708527/implementing-a-plugin-system-in-c-or-c)
- [Xcode & iOS - Create Plugins?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6834859/xcode-ios-create-plugins)
- [How can I combine multiple iPhone applications in to one application?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3054788/how-can-i-combine-multiple-iphone-applications-in-to-one-application)
- [Objective-C Plugin Architecture Security (Mac, not iPhone)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2824082/objective-c-plugin-architecture-security-mac-not-iphone)
- [Objective-C and designing a plugin mechanism](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5854710/objective-c-and-designing-a-plugin-mechanism)

https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/CoreFoundation/Conceptual/CFPlugIns/CFPlugIns.html

You have to choose right platform for creating plugins and then you need to link installed plugins to correct app
I don't think you'll be able to check that before installing plugins the app has to be installed

Second way will be using `in-app purchase` and downloading plugins to program data directory
I think the second way is more usable and more valid, because `in AppStore cannot be sold application which is not standalone`, and depends on another app.

Comment: Thank you very much ,you answer is very usefull I will take some time  to look you linked data, Thank you.

Comment: just note, that instead of "thank you" is better to vote up on answer, and if it solves your case/question, use the green ticker on left side of answer to accept it. that's how ti works here