# How to create an iOS app add-on?

Tags: ios, api-design

Is it possible to create an API inside an iOS app to let 3rd party developers create app add-on that are downloadable for users inside the app?

I could not find any ressources for this topic online.

Comment: https://developer.apple.com/app-extensions/

Comment: Possible duplicate of [how to add one or more plugin to an exist app](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7008545/how-to-add-one-or-more-plugin-to-an-exist-app)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that's going to go against the app store guidelines if your intention is that the 3rd party developers write code, which will be downloaded and executed.

There's something of a grey area between legitimate uses and illegitimate uses of downloaded code:

Legitimate Example 1: Something like Hopscotch where children are creating simple fun shared games. These can be considered user generated content.

Legitimate Example 2: A game which is driven by scripts allows for the run-time downloading of patches to fix bugs in the scripts or even to add new levels. I believe such usages have been rejected occasionally in the past, but are generally accepted these days.

The relevant guideline from the [guidelines](https://developer.apple.com/app-store/review/guidelines/#user-generated-content) is (emphasis mine):

> 2.5.2 **Apps should be self-contained in their bundles**, and may not read or write data outside the designated container area, **nor may they download, install, or execute code**, including other iOS, watchOS, Mac OS X, or tvOS apps.

And the all-encompassing:

> We will reject apps for any content or behavior that we believe is over the line. What line, you ask? Well, as a Supreme Court Justice once said, "I'll know it when I see it". And we think that you will also know it when you cross it.

If your idea is to create some sort of app-store within your app-store app, then I would abandon it immediately, because that's going to be way over Apple's line.

That said, you haven't given much detail about your app, so I might have made wrong assumptions about where you're thinking of going.

Comment: Thanks for this comprehensive answer. The app is a chat app. The add-ons could for example be a new view in the tab bar that integrates a news feed using a 4th party API. I guess that would be over the line then because it has not much to do with the original app purpose one could argue.